# Google maps on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I'm working on a project which use Google maps v2. I've tried many emulators configurations (even genymotion) unfortunately i didn't make it work.

Can someone please show how he made it work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recent version of Genymotion no longer contains the ARM library support and Google Apps. I believe this is due to legal reasons, since they are now selling Genymotion as a product for developers.

Build a new VM from the new version of Genymotion and start the VM. Make sure you know what version you selected!

1. Download Google Apps zip package from: http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps

a.      Pick version that is compatible with the Android version on your VM

b.      Drag and drop the zip file onto the Genymotion VM window

c.       You’ll get a question “Do you want to flash...” Say OK

d.      Reboot the device by either closing the window or holding the power button to power off the VM

e.      On reboot, Google Apps should be installed and you can login to a Gmail account

f.        Note, some Google apps will probably crash on first run

2.       Flash ARM library libhoudini(google):

a.       Download zip file(libhoudini.zip)

b.       Drag and drop zip file to flash to the system

c.       Reboot again

At this point, you should have ARM support and Google apps. Please let me know if you have problems or something doesn’t work correctly.

Comment: Actually, i managed to make it work on genymotion, now i have only the zoom button but not the map.

Comment: strange. Google maps had this issue in the past but it is fixed now. Try deleting that particular emulator and try on new instance, hope it works

Answer (score 0):

you can't run Google Maps v2 on the Android emulator.